# Tag Clean-up: Recording and Field-Recording

Tags: discussion, support, tag-synonyms, tag-removal-request, tag-synonym-request

#### Recording Tags

This first tagging issue I noticed while editing [this question](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/35309/recording-audio-from-keayboard-to-laptop-via-sound-interface). As of writing this, my edit has not been approved, but I attempted to add tags and fix some things for clarity.

The tag [recording](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recording) and [audio-recording](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio-recording) have little to no discernable distinction. I propose that these are consolidated. Though [audio-recording](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio-recording) has more uses, [recording](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recording) is my preference for the sake of simplicity. It could be argued, though, since there are other forms of recording, such as [dialogue-recording](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialogue-recording), that [audio-recording](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio-recording) is more clearly general.

#### Field-Recording

Just a small note here that there exist both tags [field-recording](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field-recording) and [fieldrecording](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fieldrecording). Clearly the latter should be replaced for clarity.

Comment: I agree - the context of the site is 'audio', it doesn't make sense to have both recording and audio-recording.

Comment: `audio-recording` doesn't even have a description, so even if there *is* a difference, it's currently impossible for anyone to know which one is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

[fieldrecording](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fieldrecording) has been changed to [field-recording](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field-recording).

As for the recording tags, this is probably something that needs discussed.  I can see an argument both ways...